# Downloading iplayer to iphone

Tags: video, iphone, download

Does anyone know the easiest way to get downloaded files from BBC iplayer onto the iphone?

These download to a folder BBC/Repository as a .mp4 but itunes seems unable to import these.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the project iplayer-dl (or similar) which is a ruby app which downloads the mp4s which normally work on the iphone.

It's fairly easy to use, and if you are on windows, there is a binary you can get (ie, a .exe). Of course, you need to be in the UK, or get a good proxy server. I think it's not working at the moment - the author (not me :) ) said he was going to fix it when he gets back from holiday, which was saturday. It's an easy fix (I fixed mine in the source).

the ones that the iplayer desktop app downloads are encrypted somehow - not sure HOW, but they are....